# restoring a repository from a .git folder

Tags: linux, git, backup, directory, restore

Due to how a (now deceased) server was organized, we lost the os and most git configs, but have 100% healthy and intact (according to *git fsck --full* performed after connecting the surviving drive to a different machine) .git folder for the projects (4 projects)

Now we have a new server.

How do we restore from .git folders?

None of us are git professionals, so pardon if it is a stupid question

Comment: What do you mean with "server"? A wide-spread workflow is: N development machines (with non-bare repos and thus a .git folder) and 1 centralized "server" with a bare repo (and thus _no_ .git folder) where all developers push to. Is/was that your situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

In the side of the server:

```
git init --bare
```

Meaning:

1. You create the repository

In the side of the client:

```
git remote add name_url
git push origin master
```

Meaning:

1. You include the remote server
2. You push your local content to the server

Alternative you can copy the project that you have in your client (including the .git) into the server. This is not a very good idea if the version of git is not the same in the server and the client.

Comment: If you _copy_ the local repo (non-bare) to the server (bare), then it's better to place the __content__ of the local .git folder into the server's directory.

Comment: I do not mean this in an insulting way, just a pragmatic one. Troncador's answer is the correct one and is _so_ obvious to anybody who knows even a small amount about git that I worry JohnEdwardsCummings that your group will continue to get yourselves in trouble unless you have somebody who knows what they're doing with git.

Comment: Perl Dog: I try to said what you say.  was it unclear my explanation?